# Posts and comments with ember data async

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models, a post model and a comment model. I would like to download the comments asynchronously, and it works fine with the following models.

```
//models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    date: attr('string'),
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    comments: hasMany('comment', {async: true})
});

//models/comment.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    date: attr('string'),
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    value: attr('string')
});
```

Although sometimes, a post can have hundreds of comment ids, and I don't want to load all the comments in one shot, this can be too big, so I'd like to limit the request.

If I am doing the following, it will download all the comments at once.

```
this.store.findRecord('post', 1).then((post) => {
    post.get('comments'); //Will call the server to load all the comments
});
```

I'm not even able to access the ids to get them manually through the store, as when I call `.get('comments')` it loads them all.

I'm wondering what could be my best solution to avoid to load all the comments in one shot?

Thanks

Comment: What versions of Ember and Ember Data are you using?

Comment: I would suggest looking into pagination, I believe you can do it for relationships as well.

Comment: Ember and Ember Data 2.1

Comment: Yes you need pagination. e.g "?post=1?page=1?per_page=20 "

Comment: How can I do that with what I have?